# Codeigniter Plivo PHLO - Curl sending json

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, curl

I would like to understand why the "HTTPHEADER" option is not interpreted correctly. The sending is going well, but the Plivo server can't read my request which doesn't arrive in JSON.

Below, the helper Codeigniter:

```
    function launchCall($from, $to, $position, $message){

    $CI = &get_instance();
    $CI->load->config('plivo');

    $data = array("from" => $from, "to" => $to, "position" => $position, "message" => $message);                                                                    
    $data_string = json_encode($data);          

    $url = 'https://phlorunner.plivo.com/v1/account/YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';                                        

    $ch = curl_init();    

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);  

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $CI->config->item('AUTH_ID') . ":" . $CI->config->item('AUTH_TOKEN'));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "not interpreted correctly"? Why do you think you can force the server which you post data to to accept some format?

Comment: on localhost? or live server?

Comment: I tried it from "Postman" by forcing the Content-Type and it works perfectly well.

However, when I run the script from our live server, it doesn't work. 
According to information received from Plivo, the problem comes from there, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

There are no issues with your code. The payload is received fine. The reason your attempt is failing is minor and could be fixed in a jiffy.
The Caller ID (from) needs to be a valid phone number in E.164 phone number format. Add Country code to your Caller ID and your PHLO should work fine.